# How to set my canvas drawings visible to anther user who opens same page where actions performed using paper.js script

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html5-canvas, paperjs

I am working with paper.js in asp.net mvc4 application ,which helps in drawing on canvas region of HTML. I need your support for my requirement:
   When I draw on my canvas I want to make visible these drawings on other canvas who opened same page over internet.
   Paper.js provides a global variable called project.activeLayer to access items on view. I saved cavnas data in JSON format from active Layer , then I send this data through server communication. How can I rebuild the view in the canvas with same data. ?
  (or)
 Is there any way to do this without transmission of data.?

Thanks,
surbob.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be simple.  What you're talking about is basically the same as a chat room with caht cleints in the browser.  You need to send the canvas data to the server, and then have the server update any other clients connected to it.

Probably the best place to start would be a chat-room sample and modify the code to handle the canvas data.  The [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) real-time communications library would probablyhelp to make tings a lot simpler, and it has good samples to get you going.

Comment: Thanks Cooper, but I dont want data transmission between server and client.My situation is not able to use  global variable called project.activeLayer in a proper way for getting active layer to another variable.

Comment: So you have the canvas open in your browser and you're drawing on it. The canvas that you want the drawings to be copied to, is that open in the same browser, or in a browser on a different machine?